# How to count results from database?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to count the result fetched from database

```
$t = Activation::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();

$w=(count($t));
dd($w);
```

I expect to see the number of results fetched

Comment: `->first()` returns one result, what exactly are you trying to count here?

Comment: if you want count of query results just use `->count()` like this:
`Activation::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->count()`

but your example is unreasonable because user_id should be unique and always return 1 or 0

Comment: $w=(count($t));

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 solved it

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong... Please read the [Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)

With `first()` function you're getting just the first result of the set returned from your query. To make your code work you should use the `get()` function. and the `dd($w)` will return the correct result.

Anyway there are specific [aggregate functions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) to achieve your goal, just changing your code from

```php
Activation::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();

// output: {"user_id": 1, "email": 'test@example.com', [...]}
```

to

```php
Activation::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->count();

// output: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a laravel count method.

```
$t = Activation::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->count();
dd($t);

$ty = Activation::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->count();
dd($ty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `first()` that will return only one object if found. use `get()` and then use  count.

```
$t = Activation::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
$w = count($t);
```

If you just want to count then use `count()`

```
Activation::where('user_id',$user->id)->count();
```